# Swift: How to add floors to my game?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently experimenting with a game. I want to create floating "floors" or "platforms" — like what you would see in a game like Doodle Jump or Mario. I currently have SKSpriteNodes with line images as textures. I initially set the SKPhysicsBody to a rectangle, but the lines, or "floors" will end up disrupting my main sprite's movement when they collide. I want the "floors" to have properties that allows you to land on them. Also, if you are underneath the floors, I want to allow it so that you can jump through it and land on top of it.

```
func addLines (){

    var lineTexture = SKTexture (imageNamed: "redline.png");
    var lineMovement = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0, duration: Double(self.frame.size.width / 100));
    line = SKSpriteNode (texture: lineTexture);


    line.position = CGPointMake (CGRectGetMidX (self.frame) + self.frame.size.width / 3, CGFloat(random ()) % (self.frame.size.height - 30));

    //line.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake (lineTexture.size().width, lineTexture.size().height));
    //line.physicsBody!.dynamic = false;

    line.runAction (lineMovement);
    self.addChild (line);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically change your `collisionBitMask` depending on the state of your sprite. Best way to do this is to set up a `contactBitMask` flag special for your platforms.

When your sprite makes contact with your platform, you evaluate whether or not of the platform is below the sprite.  if the platform is below the sprite, enable the `collisionBitMask` flag for platforms, otherwise remove the flag

You should be able to do this all on the platform, I.E.  the platform should enable/disable collision with sprite depending on sprite position, but sprite should not have a collisionBitMask to the platform, because if you enable it on the sprite, then you can't have 2 platforms next to each other like a vertical staircase.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way is to detect the player's position in the game. If the player's position is below the floating floors, there is only "dummy" floors (like only image sprite, but no physics body); Once the player's position is above the floor, the floor immediately has a physics body.

The detail implementation could be different. For example, you can store a bool to determine whether the floor has a physics body.